# Splunk: How to get N-most-recent values for each group?

Tags: sorting, grouping, splunk

I've been struggling with this query for a few hours and it seems that it should be fairly straightforward, but for some reason I'm finding it quite difficult. My customer wants to see the top 2 most recent "key" for each clientType.

(Really it's the top N - but more than "first" or "last")

While some translation is done before the step I'm asking about, I have the data looking like this as the output of the query (note: due to proprietary reasons I cannot provide the actual steps above this, nor is this real data but I think it should translate OK). I've starred the records that should end up in the output.

```
out?  clientType  key            _time
----  ----------  -------------  -----------------
 *    Mobile      asfk129458715  2020-10-13 12:10Z
 *    Online      askg259750505  2020-10-12 11:59Z
 *    Email       dh8iwwih33e99  2020-10-12 11:58Z
      Online      schf38hrnf98u  2020-10-12 11:00Z
 *    Online      vn8n34rf9v83j  2020-10-12 11:56Z
 *    Mobile      sjvn98h3idv9d  2020-10-12 11:56Z
 *    Email       92hnfi928rdh9  2020-10-12 11:55Z
 *    Fax         jkcni983iiff4  2020-10-09 06:54Z
```

Now, I've been able to get this working on a smaller scale, say 1 day. but some clientTypes are not very frequent and we need to see the most recent of those as well. The output of this is to be used for certain audit purposes, and What I've found is that when I extend the search to multiple days (returning > 10,000 events), the output is erratic, and I see results that are out of order, not the most recent, or otherwise askew.

What I want to see is this - only the top 2 for each client type, sorted by time descending within each group

```
clientType  key            _time
----------  -------------  --------------
Mobile      asfk129458715  2020-10-13 12:10Z
Mobile      sjvn98h3idv9d  2020-10-12 11:56Z
Online      askg259750505  2020-10-12 11:59Z
Online      vn8n34rf9v83j  2020-10-12 11:56Z
Email       dh8iwwih33e99  2020-10-12 11:58Z
Email       92hnfi928rdh9  2020-10-12 11:55Z
Fax         jkcni983iiff4  2020-10-09 06:54Z
```

for some "what I tried", I've tried using some query code in various orders mostly revolving around `stats list(key)`, `sort 0 -_time` etc, with various "by" clauses. The output of this query will also go through some additional translation to be used in our audit system, which takes a list of keys, each wrapped in single quotes and comma-delimited.

I've used `stats delim="','"` and `mvcombine` with some success at this point in the query to get results that finally look like this. I wanted to include this as part of the question so it's clear what the end state needs to look like, in case something needs to change somewhere in the grouping and sorting section to make this easier.

```
clientType  keys           
----------  -------------
Mobile      'asfk129458715','sjvn98h3idv9d'
Online      'askg259750505','vn8n34rf9v83j'
Email       'dh8iwwih33e99','92hnfi928rdh9'
Fax         'jkcni983iiff4'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the two (or 'N') most recent events by a certain field, first sort by time then use the `dedup` command to select the first N results.

```
<your query>
| sort - _time
| dedup 2 clientType
```

Answer (score 0):

While @RichG's `dedup` option may work, here's one that uses `stats` and `mvindex`:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp clientType=* key=*
| eval comb=_time+" | "+key
| stats values(comb) as comb by clientType
```

Using [`mvindex`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.6/SearchReference/MultivalueEvalFunctions#mvindex.28MVFIELD.2CSTARTINDEX.2C_ENDINDEX.29) in its range form, instead of selecting merely the last item

```
| eval mostrecents=mvindex(comb,-1-N,-1)
```

(Of course - sub-in for `N` whatever you need)

```
| fields - comb
| mvexpand mostrecents
| rex field=mostrecent "(?<timemost>\d+)\s\|\s(?<keymost>.+)"
| table clientType timemost keymost
| eval timemost=strftime(timemost,"%c")
```

Comment: This may work for the case where N=2, I believe RichG's response truly covers the requirement
     [(Really it's the top N) but more than "first" or "last")]

Comment: @user10946195 - I've edited the question to reflect your desire for it to not merely be "2 most recent"

Comment: @user10946195 - note changes to the answer, reflecting the change in question